# Converting JSON to Array in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have this code

```
Dim x As String
x = "{'books':[{'title':'HarryPotter','pages':'134'}]}"
```

what i want to do is to convert it into array like we do in PHP using the `json_decode(x,TRUE or FALSE)` function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your string `x` does not contain an array, but a single JSON object.

Just use a JSON library like [`Json.NET`](https://json.codeplex.com/) to parse your string:

```
Dim x = "{'books':[{'title':'HarryPotter','pages':'134'}]}"

Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(x)
Console.WriteLine(result("books")(0)("title") & " - " & result("books")(0)("pages"))
```

**Output:**

> HarryPotter - 134

Comment: i cant get it to work... :p error i get is JsonConvert not declared

Comment: Have you actually added a reference to Json.NET to your project and imported the corrct namespace?

Comment: how should it be done without table name? what if i only have this
[{'title':'HarryPotter','pages':'134'}]

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, it was bugging me a lot

Answer (score 3):

@Professor Haseeb Maybe you forget to Add the following to @Dominic Kexel solution:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
```

Or use:

```
Dim result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(x)
```