# Issue accessing deserialized json data

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm new to webhooks and json but have been searching this site and the rest of google trying to figure out how to process a sendgrid json post for a project I'm working on.  I have the code working functionally but get either nothing/empty string returned for my data or an error (for unique args).

I'm using newtsonsoft.json and currently just posting to an aspx page and trying to output the data to tets the process.  I have a fixed sample json post that I'm sending.

All info below - would really appreciate someone advising me where I've screwed up please as I've been searching for samples and solutions and am stuck!

Code

```
Public Class sgData

    Public Property sgEmail() As String
    Public Property sgTimestamp() As String
    Public Property sgSMTPID() As String
    Public Property sgEvent() As String
    Public Property sgCategory() As String
    Public Property sgEventID() As String
    Public Property sgMsgID() As String
    Public Property sgUserAgent() As String
    Public Property sgIP() As String
    Public Property sgURL() As String
    Public Property sgASMGroup() As String
    Public Property sgUniqueArgs As uArgs

End Class

Public Class uArgs

    Public Property CB() As String
    Public Property emailType() As String
    Public Property prodGroup() As String

End Class

Public Class xhandler

    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim whReader As New StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream)
        Dim strjson = whReader.ReadToEnd()
        Dim sgResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of sgData))(strjson)
        For Each item In sgResponse
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("-> event=" & item.sgEvent & Chr(13))    ' is empty/nothing
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("-> CB=" & item.sgUniqueArgs.CB & Chr(13))    ' throws an error = Object reference not set to an instance of an object
        Next

    End Sub

End Class
```

And the json content...

```
[
  {
    "email": "example@test.com",
    "timestamp": 1517928354,
    "smtp-id": "<14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555>",
    "event": "processed",
    "category": "cat facts",
    "sg_event_id": "uMaJLSrLHH96LFwwpCju5w==",
    "sg_message_id": "14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0",
    "unique_args": {
        "CB": "111",
        "emailType": "invite",
        "prodGroup": "REFEX"
    }
  },
  {
    "email": "example@test.com",
    "timestamp": 1517928354,
    "smtp-id": "<14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555>",
    "event": "deferred",
    "category": "cat facts",
    "sg_event_id": "3pSLStZrkwJ52nPCBa6z-Q==",
    "sg_message_id": "14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0",
    "response": "400 try again later",
    "attempt": "5",
    "unique_args": {
        "CB": "222",
        "emailType": "invite",
        "prodGroup": "REFEX"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Probably the issue is because of that line: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of sgData))(strjson). Search deserialization to list issue.

Comment: Additional: not sure, but I think deserialization unique_args to sgUniqueArgs  won't work out of the box coz of diff naming. Error is because deserialization was not successful and you item.sgUniqueArgs. was null/nothing

Comment: First - write simple test to make sure you can properly deserialzie json. strjson = "yourjason"  then Dim sgResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of sgData))(strjson) then check object in debug mode.

Comment: Well, I guess that's the point - I've tried various different way of deserializing the data with varying degrees of success.  Am working on parsing it directly as advised below...

Comment: Generate classes from JSON https://jsonutils.com/. May still need to add attribute deserializeAs as the names are with hyphens..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a JSON library like Json.NET to parse your string.
Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079275/converting-json-to-array-in-vb-net#23079446) could help you.

Comment: Thanks - I steered away from that as I wasn't able to get the unique_args 'sub-object' out how I wanted, but it does output stuff. Do I just do another deserialize on the unique_args then, or convert it to a dictionary or something?

Answer (score 0):

OK sorted it.  Just deserialized it directly into an object and then deserialized the unique_args into a dictionary to lop through, completely ignoring the classes I created.

Working code snippet below:

```
Dim sgResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strjson)
For Each item In sgResponse
    sgEventType = item("event").ToString
    candEmail = item("email").ToString
    Dim uniqueArgs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(item("unique_args").ToString)
    CB = uniqueArgs("CB")
    emailType = uniqueArgs("emailType")
    prodGroup = uniqueArgs("prodGroup")
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("-> event=" & sgEventType & ", email=" & candEmail & ", CB=" & CB & ", emailType=" & emailType & ", prodGroup=" & prodGroup & Chr(13))
Next
```

And it outputs the following:

```
-> event=processed, email=example@test.com, CB=111, emailType=invite, prodGroup=REFEX
-> event=deferred, email=example@test.com, CB=222, emailType=invite, prodGroup=REFEX
```

thx, just couldn't get my head around it earlier for some reason :-D