# How do you make Selly.gg generate a product key, with your software knowing what it is?

Tags: vb.net

I'm crating a program at the moment which has a product key feature on it. I've been constantly re-searching on Google to try and find a way to get an auto-generated software key (From Selly, that is), with my program knowing what that key is, and then when the user types in the provided product key they get in email, it lets them through.

I was thinking of using a method where a Label.Text is generated, and the user gets an email of what the Label.Text which they can use as a product key.

With that method, heres my code:

```
Dim validchars As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    Dim rand As New Random()
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        Dim idx As Integer = rand.Next(0, validchars.Length)
        Dim randomChar As Char = validchars(idx)
        sb.Append(randomChar)
    Next i

    Dim randomString = sb.ToString()

    Label1.Text = randomString
```

However, I'm looking for a more ***secure*** way to do it.

Comment here if you need any more information.

Comment: So you use selly.gg? Then you could just ask for the order ID and check if the order is valid with a query: https://developer.selly.gg/#webhooks

Comment: But what I'm asking is how. @MarcoSadowski

Comment: I'm not good with this stuff @MarcoSadowski

Comment: create a http query to get the info, use a JSON library like [Json.NET](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=json) to parse your string.

if you need a code example how you can work with values of a JSON file then you can check out [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079275/converting-json-to-array-in-vb-net).

please try it yourself first, edit the post with code that you tried and then I can help you if you still fail.

Comment: Do you have Facebook or something to talk on about this? I understand what you're saying, but I'm still not sure how to do it. I'm just the type of guy who needs super detailed steps. What do you mean by 'parse your string' what string?