# Parse JSON string in ideally VB or C# as a last resort

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I need to be able to parse the following string ideally in VB or C# if not VB - I have tried many methods found online but cant get any to work - has someone got working quick sample code to help me through at all please?

I have tried using json.net / newtonsoft but got no where - a bit rusty!

```
Dim json As String = "[{""posX"":36,""posY"":74,""data"":{""type"":""A""},""html"":""A""},{""posX"":243,""posY"":77,""data"":{""type"":""A""},""html"":""A""},{""posX"":32,""posY"":279,""data"":{""type"":""B""},""html"":""B""},{""posX"":242,""posY"":285,""data"":{""type"":""c""},""html"":""c""}]"
```

The values of interest to me are posX, posY and html

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the sample from the Newtonsoft documentation.

Comment: Ive tried - converted the c# to vb and always get Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Your input works fine. It is just `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)`. The C# and VB.NET are literally identical.

Comment: If you dont post the code you are trying to get to work, how can we help you fix the code?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json.NET is the correct way.
Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079275/converting-json-to-array-in-vb-net#23079446) could help you.

```
Dim json As String = "{'position':[{""posX"":36,""posY"":74,""data"":{""type"":""A""},""html"":""A""},{""posX"":243,""posY"":77,""data"":{""type"":""A""},""html"":""A""},{""posX"":32,""posY"":279,""data"":{""type"":""B""},""html"":""B""},{""posX"":242,""posY"":285,""data"":{""type"":""c""},""html"":""c""}]}"
Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)
Console.WriteLine(result("position")(0)("posX") & " - " & result("position")(0)("posY") & " - " & result("position")(0)("html"))
```

Output should be

> 36 - 74 - A

... did not tested it yet but I hope it brings you on the right track.

Comment: Yes that worked great thank you.  Is there a way to establish how many rows as such there are to replace the (0) with (i) assuming i is in my for loop to loop through them all?

Comment: yes you can loop it. you could do something like "Do Until result IsNot Null" - Just play around with it!